# HTML5 Break an image into tiles with the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a large image that I would like to break into 10x10 tile images using the html5 canvas.  I can draw the large image to the canvas easily and then use getImageData to grab the pixel data for a specific region.

Is there an easy way to put that image data (which is a pixel array) in an image html element or do I have to create a new canvas, putImageData the pixel array and then call toDataURL?

Comment: http://craftymind.com/factory/html5video/CanvasVideo.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get image from canvas element and use it in img src tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257781/can-i-get-image-from-canvas-element-and-use-it-in-img-src-tag)

Comment: @bfavaretto thta is using toDataURL to get the entire image.  I want to get a dataURI for a specific region of the canvas, not the entire thing

Comment: @Shanimal that video looks like it has good stuff thanks

Comment: Yeah the source code is there as well, There is an example where he's using a 3d graphics engine.
http://craftymind.com/factory/html5video/CanvasVideo3D.html

Comment: Hm, you could use a separate canvas as a buffer to create each slice. But did you see epascarello's suggestion below? Do you really need a canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why go through all of that trouble with canvas? Use the image as a background and show the portions that you want by positioning it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="myImage section1"></div>
<div class="myImage section2"></div>
<div class="myImage section3"></div>
<div class="myImage section4"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.myImage {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image:url('myImage.png');
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.section2 {
    background-position: 100px 0;
}

.section3 {
    background-position: 0 100px;
}

.section4 {
    background-position: 100px 100px;
}
```

Comment: I need to use this in a canvas application but in general this is a good answer so accepting.