# representing canvas image as an actual image in other pages

Tags: javascript, php, html

here is my canvas image in a page called `canvas.php`

```
  <html>
    <body>
    <style type="text/css">
    table
    {
    border=5;
    }
    </style>
    <p><canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
                 "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
                   "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:40px'>" +
                     "<table><tr><td>HI</td><td>Welcome</td></tr><tr><td>Hello</td><td>World</td></tr> </table>" +
                   "</div>" +
                 "</foreignObject>" +
               "</svg>";
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var img = new Image();
    var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
    img.src = url;
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i want to get this image as an actuall image in the other pages .... basically i want to able to do this in  `otherpage.php`

```
<img src="www.mysite.com/canvas.php" />
```

this image dynamically changes from time to time .. so i dont want to save it ... just want to show it as it is in another pages without canvas

Comment: no iframe is out of question .... if this doesn't work i have to create the image with php

Comment: Well that you can’t give an HTML document as the src for an img element should be pretty obvious …

Comment: It is not possible without an iframe. Canvas is an own element and only accessible through JavaScript.
But you can convert it to a data URI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257781/can-i-get-image-from-canvas-element-and-use-it-in-img-src-tag

Comment: @movabo i'm not sure how that would work in a external page ... should i printout `canvas.toDataURL()` (somehow ! ) in my `canvas.php` as only  output of that page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `canvas` in a PHP file and call that PHP using `img`,

- Canvas works with Javascript  PHP file header must be set to
- image/png or image/jpg `header( "Content-type: image/png" );`

"iframe is out of question" ok!

Your only solution is use [PHP image](https://www.php.net/image), [PHP: imagecreate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php)

create the file `myImg.php`:

```
<?php
header( "Content-type: image/png" ); // set this php file as png file
$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 200 ); // image width & height
$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 245,245,245 ); // set the background color
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255,66,121 ); // text color
imagestring( $my_img, 10, 50, 90, "Hello World", $text_colour );  // Our Hello World text!
imagepng( $my_img ); // outputs PNG image 
?>
```

index.html

```
<img src="myImg.php" /> // this will output the image from myImg.php
```

See these resources:

- [How to Create an Image in PHP](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/create-image.shtml)
- [PHP: GD library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Comment: thanks , i know how to create an image with php .... the thing is i have to create a image from html table which is very very hard using just php gd lib ...