# download image that generated from html2canvas on button click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, image

so I have image generated from table using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com).
The output will be placed in canvas.
My problem is what to do when user click "Download Image" button so the image can be downloaded to their computer ?

I already google some way to do it but it all of it are not make sense. There is no code that show how to retrieve the data image and then download it to the computer.

there will be two ways to do this :

1. still use html2canvas to convert the table to image and then use jquery to download the image
2. use another solution to convert the table to image and then use c# (code behind) to download it

so which should I do ? or maybe you have any other solution ?

EDIT : **I've already got the data url**, but I can only send the image to new tab using window.open(image_data_url), not download it. But a minute ago I found the solution. You can just **use "a" tag and then add attribute "download=[file_name.jpg]" and fill the "href" value with the data url**. But still it's not what I want. **If I use this I will need two buttons, button for converting table to image and button for download the image**. Is there any possible solution with single click you got the data url and then download it as image ?

EDIT : **the solution above can't be used in IE**. So maybe there is another solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to convert the html element, then save as image on your local using jQuery. Take a look at my sample code :

```
    $("#btnSave").click(function() {
        html2canvas($("#map"), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                        theCanvas = canvas;
                        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                        Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                        $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                        // Clean up
                        //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
                }
        });
});
```

here's the real live : http://www.nanonimos.com/drag-pin-ID-convert/

Comment: `html2canvas` isn't a built-in javascript method.  If it's part of a library, please link it in your answer

Comment: Ok. i forgot to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

Use toDataURL or toBlob on the canvas and link to the generated url.
When using toBlob you need to use URL.createObjectURL(blob) on it).

Im wondering what version of google you're using since when i google "canvas get image"
I get plenty results with ready to use codesnippets.

Like:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement#Example.3A_Getting_the_data-url_for_a_canvas

or

[Can I get image from canvas element and use it in img src tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257781/can-i-get-image-from-canvas-element-and-use-it-in-img-src-tag)

Comment: oh yeah I forgot to write down that I've already get the data url. But I just can link the image to new tab, not download it. But a minute ago I found the solution for download the image. Just use the "a" tag and add "download" attribute and fill the "href" value with the data url. But it still not what I want. What I want is with a single click the image got converted and then the browser download it.