# How to store HTML5 canvas as an image in a list of frames?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Trying to make a simple animation engine for an HTML5 game. I have a timeline along the top composed of frame previews and a wireframe editor with a stickman for testing on a bigger, bottom canvas.

When I switch frames, I use drawImage() to copy the bottom canvas to a small frame preview along the top.

Is there a way to save the bottom canvas' current state in an array (each item corresponding to each frame) so that I can use drawImage() to place them as onion skins?

Here's the project if you want to see it visually:
https://jsfiddle.net/incon/owrj7e5z/

(If you look at the project, it doesn't really work yet, it's a big work in progress and is very glitchy)

This is what I was trying, and it works for previews, but won't redraw as onion skins on the bottom canvas.

```
var framePreviews = [undefined,undefined,undefined....];
var c = document.getElementById('bottomCanvas');
var tContext = document.getElementById('timelineCanvas').getContext('2d');
framePreviews[simulation.currentFrame] = c; // save canvas in an array
tContext.drawImage(framePreviews[simulation.currentFrame], simulation.currentFrame*60, 0, 60, 60/c.width*c.height); // draw the canvas 60px wide in the timeline
```

Comment: small suggestion you could try to use https://stackblitz.com/ for managing and sharing your project

Comment: after checking your code you can create image for your frame and keep it outside of canvas using technique described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234492/copy-a-part-of-canvas-to-image

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Don't.

An image is really heavy, whatever the mean of saving it you'll choose, there will always at least be once the ImageBitmap of your full sized canvas that will need to be stored in your browser's memory, and in a few frames, you'll blow it out.

You don't do any heavy calculations in your app, so you don't need to store these as images.

Instead only **save the drawing commands, and redo the drawings every time.**

---

Now, for the ones who do have to save computationally heavy frames, then the best is to [generate an ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) from your canvas, but once again, this should be used only if drawing this one frame takes more than 16ms.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to save the drawing commands in Javascript, or do I need to create a list of points, lines, line widths, etc. to iterate through?

Comment: Yes save all the points positions, and any other feature you will add (maybe colors, linewidth etc) and save these in a common format that you'll just have to iterate through when drawing each frame.