# Canvas to PNG on Client Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a canvas and I want to convert it and show in a  tag. I know we can convert canvas to image by using `toDataURL()` and `toBlob()` but both method give me base64 data which is not a image.

```js
$("#upload_feedback_btn").on("click", function() {
let feedbackSrc = document.getElementById("capture").toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);
        $("#feedback_canvas_image").append("<img id='upload_canvas_img' src="+feedbackSrc+">");
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get image from canvas element and use it in img src tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257781/can-i-get-image-from-canvas-element-and-use-it-in-img-src-tag)

Answer (score 4):

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillRect(50,50,50,50);

var img = new Image();
img.src = can.toDataURL();
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/vgmFN/

Comment: Thanks but I did the same. Its not what I want. Its give me a base64 image but I want png/jpg image

Comment: Do you want to download png / jpeg image type? @shehzad940

Comment: No, I am able to download but I want to append image in body as a png/jpeg image....my code append the image but in base64.

Comment: Actually I want to copy canvas on clipboard so that I can paste it as an image in MS-Word / Wordpad

Answer (score 0):

Use this, pure javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

make_base();

function make_base()
{
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'img/base.png';
  base_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(base_image, 100, 100);
  }
}
```