# Image src local file in popup window open with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, google-chrome-extension, src

I've made a Chrome Extension that:

Takes a screenshot of a website, opens anew window, cuts the image using canvas, and downloads the image. Now I want to display the image so I create an image and set its path to file:///C:/Users/myuser/Downloads/myfile.png.

But the image doesn't show up. I tried removing the "file" or setting a timeout but nothing works, however when I click the image link in the dev console it takes me to the picture and it works.

Here's the code from ´background.js´:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function(image){
        var x = window.open();

        var cv = x.document.createElement('canvas');
        x.document.body.appendChild(cv);

        var canvas = x.document.querySelector('canvas');
        canvas.width = 928
        canvas.height = 490;

        var img = new Image();

        var code = new Date().getTime();

        img.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(this, 315, 138, 928, 490, 0, 0, 928, 490);

            var toCopy = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            var link = x.document.createElement('a');
            link.download = code + '.png';
            link.href = toCopy;
            link.click();       

            setTimeout(function(){
                var el = new Image();
                el.src = 'file:///C:/Users/myuser/Downloads/'+code+'.png';

                x.document.body.appendChild(el);

                x.console.log(x.location);
            }, 2000);


            canvas.parentElement.removeChild(canvas);
        }

        img.src = image;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    });
});
```

Comment: code you add some code please?

Comment: Code added @JSmith

Comment: I think browsers can't read files from the local disk and embed them into a page via script. It would be a huge security hole. Anyway even if it was possible, you can't even assume the user actually has a C drive. Not every device runs Windows. And if they do, you're assuming that they kept their downloads folder in a specific place. You even assumed their username! going to the URL separately in another window is a separate thing, that's allowed since the user is explicitly requesting that (rather than a script trying to do it for them)

Comment: It's just to use on my local machine, it's kind of like a hack to make some task easier for me. Anyway, I tried doing: window.open(thePath); and it tries to download the image again, is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Yes I think so. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257781/can-i-get-image-from-canvas-element-and-use-it-in-img-src-tag. Just set the img src directly to the DataURL generated by the canvas. I haven't tried it myself but it seems pretty plausible. That way the data just stays within the page, it never has to trouble your hard disk.

Comment: The problem is I need to copy the image (to paste it in an excel) and for that to work, the image has to be a file, otherwise it throws an error.

Comment: Well you can still download it as well. And then you can easily paste or import the image from your disk into Excel.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that I need to right click and copy to make it faster.

Comment: Right-click the extension icon, click "manage", enable the file access checkbox.

Comment: I don't get "manage" when right-clicking the extension icon