# How can I extract a photo from html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to download a photo using html2canvas. I already tried to use javascript and HTML. So, I made a download process. But, there was no image in the jpg file. So, I want to solve that problem.

```js
function PrintDiv(div)  {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("photo")).then(function(canvas) {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL();
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg",
      "image/octect-stream");
    document.body.append(link);
    link.download = 'polaroid.jpg'
    link.click();
  })
}

$('#blobButton').click(function() {
  PrintDiv($('#photo'));
})
```

```css
.polaroid {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #777;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
  background-color: white;
}

.polaroid img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.polaroid div {
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="polaroid" id="photo">
  <img src="https://file.mk.co.kr/meet/neds/2017/03/image_readtop_2017_163255_14890579952804146.jpg" />
  <div class="text">
    <p>2013년02월27일 오후3:00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="to">TO {{photo.info.to_name}}</div>

  <div class="message" style="text-align:center">{{photo.info.message}}</div>

  <div class="from" style="text-align:right">FROM: {{photo.info.from_name}}</div>
</div>

<button id="blobButton">DOWNLOAD</button>
```

I want to download a photo like below.

[image]

Comment: Consider using a stack snippet instead of putting the code inside a blockquote.

Comment: I can not see any button with id `blobButton` (as in you js)

Comment: @לבנימלכה I added blobButton html. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get image from canvas element and use it in img src tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257781/can-i-get-image-from-canvas-element-and-use-it-in-img-src-tag)

Comment: @YoungdongKim can you look at F12 to see if there is any error?  화이팅 !!

Comment: @לבנימלכה I don't have any error. I could download file but there was strange image like this.

![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/42408554/60010266-61c29d00-96b2-11e9-96d8-bc23bc5f27d3.png)

Comment: I know when I run it I got same result

Comment: @לבנימלכה I don't know why... :( so, is there any way to solve that problem?

Comment: do you use local image or this link?

Comment: @לבנימלכה I'm using web images which have URL link.

Comment: I'd say the problem is that the  images aren't on the same server as the script trying to draw them on the canvas.

Comment: @obscure Oh, thanks!!! I did it!
But there is one problem. I can get just divided photo image like below.

![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/42408554/60059901-5fe7f080-9729-11e9-8e2d-0bbc40cc8037.png)