# Extracting image data url after text manipulation on canvas, and show result in Material-UI's CardMedia

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, material-ui

I am working through the following code hosted at sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-wilbur-bhhcp?fontsize=14)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import backImg from "./background.png";

const Canvas = props => {
  const canvas = useRef(null);

  const image = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    image.current.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);
      ctx.font = "40px Courier";
      ctx.fillText(props.text, 210, 75);
    };
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);
    ctx.font = "40px Courier";
    ctx.fillText(props.text, 210, 75);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={canvas} width={640} height={425} />
      <img
        ref={image}
        alt="Stackoverflow56203352"
        src={backImg}
        className="hidden"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Canvas text="TEST 123" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I am not sure how to extract the url of image after the text has been implemented on the image. i.e. in my case I want the url of image with text on it.

And I want the image to be displayed in a Material-UI's CardMedia component.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question, but I don't think you can do that...at least not going in this direction. The URL of the image points to the file itself, which doesn't have a text. The text you are drawing is only in the browser, not in the image file. So, unless you create a new image and save as a new file, you will not ble able to create a URL that points to an image with text.

Comment: Yes that is what I see also. I was wondering if there was a way to save the image with text to browser cache and get url for that ? i.e. display the modified image in browswer cache in a separate display.

Comment: By doing `canvas.current.toDataURL()` and adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` to your <canvas> element, it will give you a base64 string containing the information of the modified canvas and you can use it as a URL. Does it work for you?

Comment: You can only get it as a data URL as such. That is by using `canvas.toDataURL()` and this you can then use as the `src` for a image tag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257781/can-i-get-image-from-canvas-element-and-use-it-in-img-src-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may export a Canvas to a data url with the [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) method.

Like so:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);
        ctx.font = "40px Courier";
        ctx.fillText(props.text, 210, 75);
        const imgUrl = canvas.current.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  });
```

But the image must be served from the same origin otherwise you'll get this error (which happens in your sandbox):

`Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

[Resource about this error and how to deal with it](https://thisinterestsme.com/tainted-canvases/)

Working example below (I've used an image hosted by facebook because they're said to support such thing and to demonstate that the error is gone when the image is from the same origin, a permissive origin or when it has the `crossOrigin="anonymous"` attribute, open the console output in a new tab to see the result, as the OP requested, the result is shown in a CardMedia from MarterialUI):

```js
const backImg = "https://scontent-cdg2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/26907788_1614183255284072_4356465325754439623_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&_nc_oc=AQle2ac8QeR7C5HY-Z9oxWXbMdzjkDlVo8WYfhqDZArSYoEb1q1Xv5ZaE1Z4JNm7bmY&_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.xx&oh=1c12333fe33d7d3fc2e39d3794d7dab4&oe=5DC018D1";

const { CardMedia } = MaterialUI;

const Canvas = props => {
  const [finalSrc, setFinalSrc] = React.useState(null)
  const canvas = React.useRef(null);

  const image = React.useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    image.current.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);
      ctx.font = "40px Courier";
      ctx.fillText(props.text, 210, 75);
    };
  }, []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);
    ctx.font = "40px Courier";
    ctx.fillText(props.text, 210, 75);
    setFinalSrc(canvas.current.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
    
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {finalSrc && <CardMedia image={finalSrc} style={{ height: 425, width: 640 }} />}
      <canvas ref={canvas} width={640} height={425} className="hidden" />
      <img
        ref={image}
        alt="Stackoverflow56203352"
        src={backImg}
        className="hidden"
        crossOrigin="anonymous"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Canvas text="TEST 123" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Where in code is it appropriate to add this snippet ?

Comment: You can add it in the useEffect handler just after drawing the text (it depends on what you want to do with the data url really). I'm updating the answer....

Comment: I've added and modified your snippet to make a working example: triple click on the console output and copy paste it in a new tab url.

Comment: I tried making changes in the sandbox and it errors.

Comment: As I said, you cannot use an image with CORS, you need to serve it from a server with the appropriate headers set (note the value I gave to backImg in the provided snippet). Also, you forgot the `crossOrigin="anonymous"`. I'm not you will be able to make it work through codesandbox but the provided snippet is wokring (click the blue "run code snippet" button above)

Comment: So, I will never be able to display this image with text in a Cardmedia box from MaterialUI ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196147/discussion-between-zanam-and-remix23).